# Upsert always updates postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have sql query:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
WHERE updated IS NULL OR updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO UPDATE SET version = books.version + 1, updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

however even if the where clause is not true, the row is updated. Here's example: https://dbfiddle.uk/CPHvZDm3

I can't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Postgres documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html the INSERT INTO statement has two WHERE conditions:

1. `ON CONFLICT ... WHERE index_predicate` in the `conflict_target` part. Postgres needs to understand on what unique index it should react to conflicts, especially if you have multiple unique indexes on a table. You can specify the exact index name, or you can specify column name and other parameters and Postgres will try to find ("infer") corresponding index. The `index_predicate` allows to infer partial unique indexes (i.e. unique indexes that contain information only about part of the table), but any indexes that satisfy the predicate (not only partial indexes) can be inferred.
2. `DO UPDATE SET ... WHERE condition` in the `conflict_action` part. Only rows for which this `condition` expression returns true will be updated.

So you need to move you WHERE clause from the `ON CONFLICT` block to the `DO UPDATE SET` block:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    version int8 NOT NULL,
    updated timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT books_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET version = books.version + 1, updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE books.version IS NULL OR books.updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Upd: In your case the `version` cannot be NULL and you don't need the `books.version IS NULL` condition. In case you need to allow NULLs be aware that `NULL + 1` will be `NULL` (thanks @dwhitemv for noticing) so you will need to modify the SET statement using COALESCE or conditions.

Comment: thank you so much for in-depth explanation! I made mistake, there should have been books.updated IS NULL , not version. I'll fix my question, but that doesn't really change anything. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `WHERE` clause to after the `DO UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET version = books.version + 1, 
updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE version IS NULL OR updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

That said, `version` will always be set to NULL if it is already NULL as NULL+1=NULL.